# Load Leaflet map in canvas element

Tags: leaflet, html5

I am working with leaflet tiles loading tiles to a map div

http://jsfiddle.net/tBCd5/

I am now playing with some html5 canvas distortions like below

http://jsfiddle.net/UF4PK/

It would be cool to load base tiles to a canvas and then be able to use the above distortions on the base map.

Is it possible to load my map tiles into a canvas element rather than a div?

I have seen examples of creating canvas overlays but not an example where base tiles are loaded directly to the canvas element.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue today-- I needed to load each tile into a separate canvas element, then operate on each to pixel of each tile to transform the image.

Using `L.tileLayer.canvas` and [this example](http://johngravois.com/lerc-leaflet) from John Gravois I was able to grab each tile, access the pixels, and then invert the colors (inversion code from [this Mozilla Developer Network help page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)).

I'm using an Esri ImageService of Toronto to test this approach:
http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer

I've created Gists of the regular tiles ([raw](https://gist.github.com/mappingvermont/32e9b947fc7bf60c91cecd460fc7b0bf), [rendered](http://rawgit.com/mappingvermont/32e9b947fc7bf60c91cecd460fc7b0bf/raw/9d59cdf8681e942425fe36fc6a551117e757fa03/leaflet_canvas.html)) and the inverted tiles ([raw](https://gist.github.com/mappingvermont/c7056e7cd0f68af6f75c98d493ead337) and [rendered](http://rawgit.com/mappingvermont/c7056e7cd0f68af6f75c98d493ead337/raw/fa72354cf121b95af7af2e9bdcb2a0356e3324e3/leaflet_canvas_invert.html)).